# About square rooting when calculating a normal vector to a surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am encountering the following problem:

Find a normal vector to the surface below
$$z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \ at \ (3,1,1)$$.

So what I do is to transform the surface equation into the following:
$$F(x,y,z) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} - z,$$ where $$F(x,y,z) = 0$$ before continuing.

My answer is:
$$\nabla F(3,1,1)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\pm\frac{3}{5}\textbf{i}\pm\frac{4}{5}\textbf{j}-\textbf{k})$$

However, the correct answer is:
$$\nabla F(3,1,1)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\frac{3}{5}\textbf{i}+\frac{4}{5}\textbf{j}-\textbf{k})$$

My question is: why is the $\pm$ missing? Is it because $(3,1,1)$ is in the first quadrant of $x, y, and \ z$, and the surface is an elliptical cone. Therefore, both $\textbf{i}$ and $\textbf{j}$ for the normal have to point to the positive direction.

I am extremely bad in making the decision of when to exclude the minus sign in those $\pm$ situation, and so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I find a large majority of the time the positive root is taken as otherwise it isnt a function

Comment: Are you using the horizontal line test? I thought that it only applies to 2D situation, because in surface, x, y, or z can take on more than two values while keeping the other two unknown constant. EG. a sphere $$ 4 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 $$

Comment: Well if that were the case youd have more than 2 unique normal vectors to this surface at that point and that doesnt make any sense

Comment: Can't one normal vector pointing inward and another outward, making two normal vectors?

Comment: Actually when I see the graph is a cone its apparent why you want the positive roots, the z component is negative, so the x and y must be positive so its an outward normal to the surface. If they were negative it wouldnt be orthogonal to the surface